# How create dialog box tour aps in android?

Tags: android, android-layout

how create dialog box tour aps in android ? For example in my image

[image: My image]

Comment: put a transparent view on top of your view, and add some text/images on that transparent view.

Comment: @Vlad would you like to answer with how to add a transparent  view?

Comment: just add a FrameLayout as a root of your layout, and add onother view on top of your entire view. I don't think that it is worth of an answer

Comment: Thanks All, my problem resolve.